# Open Password Protected File With PdfRenderer

Tags: android, androidpdfviewer

How can I read a password protected file using Android PdfRenderer?

doc says:

```
// create a new renderer
PdfRenderer renderer = new PdfRenderer(getSeekableFileDescriptor());

// let us just render all pages
final int pageCount = renderer.getPageCount();
for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {
   Page page = renderer.openPage(i);

    // say we render for showing on the screen
    page.render(mBitmap, null, null, Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);

    // do stuff with the bitmap 

    // close the page
    page.close();
}

// close the renderer
renderer.close();
```

This works for not password protected files.

And doc says:

```
  SecurityException If the file requires a password or the security scheme is not supported.
```

But they do not mention anything about how to handle password protected files.

I've already used third party libraries but I want to use native library if possible.

Can anyone help me?

Tks